# Pulsing effect on DIV border

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to achieve a pulsing effect for a border. Dosen't seem to work. How do I make a pulsing effect for a border?

css:

```
.DivBorder{
    border: 2px;
    border-color: #000;
 }
```

jQ:

```
function pulseEff(){ 
   $('.DivBorder').delay(1000)
      .animate({ 'border-color': 'Transparent'}, 100)
      .delay(1000)
      .animate( {'border-color': '#333'
      }, 100);
};
```

Comment: `border-color#000;` should be `border-color : #000;`

Comment: @ShaunakD: thanks. I've already fixed that. :)

Comment: @ShaunakD It's not what OP's asking.

Comment: @dfsq, Though I'm not sure, it achieves the effect. Added animate to my answer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution without `setInterval()`, this keeps running and cannot be stopped easily.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9h7ryb54/2/)**

```
(function pulseEff() {
    $('.DivBorder').delay(1000).animate({
        'border-color': 'transparent'
    }, 100).delay(1000).animate({
        'border-color': '#333'
    }, 100, pulseEff);
})();
```

You can use simple `fadeIn/Out` along with interval.

**[fadein/out Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9h7ryb54/)**

```
function pulseEff(){ 
   $('.ImgBorder').fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300);
};
var Interval;
$('#start').click(function(){
    Interval = setInterval(pulseEff,600);
});
```

or with your code; you need to increase animate times from `100` to something more relevant as `100` millisecs is too less to work out.

**[animate Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9h7ryb54/1/)**

```
function pulseEff() {
    $('.DivBorder').delay(1000)
        .animate({
        'border-color': 'transparent'
    }, 600).delay(1000)
        .animate({
        'border-color': '#333'
    }, 600);
};
var Interval;
$('#start').click(function () {
    Interval = setInterval(pulseEff, 600);
});
```